# android.R.anim.fade_out Doesn't work well, just fade in work

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I want to switch between fragment with animation.
Current, I use  this:

```
FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//fr.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit);
fr.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out);
fr.replace(R.id.fragment_container,new SwimSuitFragment());
fr.addToBackStack(null);
fr.commit();
```

the `fade_in` work well, but when I press back it goes straight to the previous fragment, and don't do the fade out animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official document;

> The popEnter and popExit animations will be played for enter/exit operations specifically when popping the back stack.

```
public abstract FragmentTransaction setCustomAnimations (int enter, 
                int exit, 
                int popEnter, 
                int popExit)
```

You should use this instead of your `setCustomAnimations`

```
fr.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out,android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out);
```